# Java Arraylist and inheritance calling right method. help

Tags: java, inheritance

I created 4 classes: *Cd*, *Dvd*, *Item* and *Database*. *Cd* and *Dvd* extend from *Item*. The *Database* class stores an `ArrayList` of *Items*.

I'm stuck on creating a method in the *Database* class, which calls the method display in either *Cd* or *Dvd*. However I managed to display the *Cds*.

How can display all items? E.g.

> Item number = 1
> CD
>
> Item number = 2
> DVD
>
> Item number = 3
> Cd

Many thanks.

**Edit**:

The display methods are different in *Cd* and *Dvd*.

```
public void displayAll() {

    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {

        Cd theCd = (Cd) items.get(i);
        // Dvd theDVD = (Dvd) items.get(i);

        System.out.println("Item Number = " + i);
        theCd.display();
         
        // theDvd.display
             
    }

}
```

My class diagram is:

[Class Diagram http://img571.imageshack.us/img571/1460/unledsca.png](http://img571.imageshack.us/img571/1460/unledsca.png)

Answer (score 1):

You probably should have `public abstract void display();` in your `Item` class.  One would imagine it makes sense for `Items`s to be able to display themselves.  Then you would implement it in `CD` and `DVD` (sounds like you already have).  Then you'd have no need for the downcast:

```
public void displayAll()
{        
     for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {  
         Item item = (Item) items.get(i); 
         System.out.println("Item Number = " + i);
         item.display();
     }
}
```

And if you're using a JDK version that supports generics, consider using `ArrayList<Item>` instead of `ArrayList`.  Then you can get rid of the `Item` cast as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should get Item from the list, and not a Cd, then just invoke the methods declared in the Item class. The methods in the subclasses will automatically be invoked if they are overriding methods.

Edit: Just checked your classdiagram. The method display should be added to the Item class, and overridden by the subclasses.

Comment: the display methods are different in cd and dvd

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `instanceof`

```
if (item instanceof Cd)
```

However, as others have said ... it may point toward a bad class design. Why do you need to know what the type is?

Comment: Yeah ... I went back and forth on that, and how now edited. There are cases where `instanceof` can make sense, but I don't know that this is one.

Answer (score 0):

Don't explicitly cast; that defeats the purpose of polymorphism.  Declare an abstract `display` method in your `Item` base class, and then override it in `Cd` and `Dvd`.

Then your loop can be:

```
List<Item> my_list = new ArrayList<Item>();

...

for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println("Item number = " + i);
    items[i].display();
}
```

This will always call the correct method.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {  


     Item theItem = (Item)items.get(i); 

     System.out.println("Item Number = " + i);
     theItem.display();


 }
```

Cast to Item, instead of CD or DVD. Make sure Item has a display() method.
Also, if you are using Java 5 or above, have a look at [generics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)